# How to use SWRevealviewcontroller libraries for more than one view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have been used the `SWrevealviewcontroller` to make my side menu and it's worked successfully, but it issues a problem when I use it for different view controller to make another side menu 
The problem is

> “View Controller“ is unreachable because it has no entry points and no identifier for runtime access via -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIViewController {

func SetREvealviewcontroller(ControllerIdentifier:String,storyboardname:String) -> Void
{
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardname, bundle: nil)
let frontNavigationController:UINavigationController
let rearNavigationController:UINavigationController
let revealController = SWRevealViewController()
var mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()



let sidebar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "MenuViewController")as! MenuViewController
let homepage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ControllerIdentifier)

frontNavigationController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: homepage)
rearNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sidebar)
frontNavigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(rgb:0x03253d)
frontNavigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(rgb:0x03253d)


revealController.frontViewController = frontNavigationController
revealController.rearViewController = rearNavigationController


frontNavigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false




mainRevealController  = revealController

appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainRevealController
}
```

Comment: self.SetREvealviewcontroller(ControllerIdentifier: "Your controller identifer", storyboardname:"Your storyboard" )
  storyboardname only require if you are using multiple storyboard.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but now I get confused about view controller identifiers. knowing that if my first view controller belongs to the SWrevealviewcontroller second, I have the side menu view controller and the main view controller which include the side menu button, which of them you mentioned in the method header?